# Python - how to append an item to a list created on the same line from some element?

Tags: python, list, append

I've got a very simple question regarding creation of lists and appending items on the same line.  I have been writing a Python Program for a school project (implementing an AI to play Blackjack) and would like to be able to do something like this:

hands = [[2,3]].append([4,5])

I need to be able to create new hands and add them to the AI players attributes for if it chooses to split, and I thought this would work but results in hands being None.  I can certainly split it into two lines, but I feel like it would be more pythonic to do it within one line.  I do not see why this doesn't work, if anyone can explain why it doesn't that would be great.  What I read it as is that hands will be set to list [[2,3]] with element [4,5] appended to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` mutates the list that it is called on, but returns `None`. So assigning the return value to a variable makes little sense. One option is:

```
hands = [[2, 3]]
hands.append([4, 5])
```

or in one line (you seem to know the lists beforehand):

```
hands = [[2, 3], [4, 5]]
# Or
# hands = [[2, 3]] + [[4, 5]]
```

Comment: Oh, duh, the second option is what I am looking for.  I shouldn't be programming late at night.  Thank you!

Comment: you should also look up extend() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm